# iOS: Allowing Only A Certain Class Access to a Specific Private Method in another Class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, methods, private

I have a few public and price methods in Class A. I use the same methods in Class B, but rather than copy and paste these methods in both classes, I want to access Class A's private methods from Class B.

The problem is I don't want any other class to be able to access these specific private methods other than B.

What's the best way to go about doing this?

P.S. I would think to make the private methods public, but then any other class can access them, which is something I don't want (this is for an open-source project). I don't mind copy and pasting methods, but I would love to know what the 'correct' way to handle something like this.

Thanks!

Comment: Well unless the other classes import Class A, that wouldnt be an issue?would it?

Comment: But other classes do import it, since Class A and Class B both have public methods that developers would access, and I rather not combine both classes since they're fairly huge and happen to be categories on different NSObjects.

Comment: What are you trying to protect against here? (And how is it relevant that this is an open-source project?) Are you worried about people mistakenly relying on methods you may want to change in the future, or are you trying to hide some functionality or something?

Comment: These are helper methods for the "main public methods", thing is I just like keeping the project clean. So when a developer is about to enter the name of a method I don't want these helper methods being suggested to them, since they'll never use them, or at least I don't want them to. It's a personal preference for me. That's also why I mentioned open-sourced project.

Answer (score 4):

You can use private headers

**MyClassA.h**

```
@interface MyClassA : NSObject

- (void)publicMethod;

@end
```

**MyClassA_Private.h**

```
#import "MyClassA.h"

@interface MyClass (Private)

- (void)packageMethod;

@end
```

Comment: I'd recommend that `MyClassA_Private.h` use a class extension and said extension by `#import`ed prior to `MyClassA`'s `@implementation`.